doxygen не отображает диаграммы If you installed Graphviz/dot after a previous failing run, try deleting the output directory and rerun doxygen
Сегодня пересобрал доксиген и увидел, что не отображается графика. У кого была такая проблема?


разобрался, на этой машине не было модуля одного, чтобы починить :
sudo apt-get install doxygen graphviz

